Can temperature dependent phonon dispersion be solved by EPW package of Quantum Espresso?
Yesterday, I posted a question (How to plot temperature dependent Phonon dispersion using Quantum Espresso?) related to temperature dependency of phonon dispersion. Would it be possible to solve this by EPW package (https://docs.epw-code.org/doc/Documentation.html) of Quantum Espresso?
Thanks!
